# Can I change android dialog theme background color programmatically?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-dialog, android-seekbar

I use dialog theme to display my activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

A seekbar in this activity.

```
alphaSeek=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar_alpha);
alphaSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                              boolean fromUser) {
    ???=progress;
}
```

Can I use the seekbar value to change color of dialog background?

---

Update:

Based on first answer, I rewrite the program, commented lines is previous version I tried. But new version is completely same effect as previous version, it only changes color inside dialog, not the background of dialog.

```
int alpha=0;
int red=0;
int green=0;
int blue=0;
SeekBar alphaSeek;

LinearLayout myActivityLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mydialog);

    myActivityLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyActivityLayout);

    alphaSeek=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    alphaSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                              boolean fromUser) {

    String hex = String.format("%02x%02x%02x%02x", alpha, red, green, blue);
    int color=(int)Long.parseLong(hex,16);
    //ColorDrawable cd=new ColorDrawable(color);
    //getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(cd);

    myActivityLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/MyActivityLayout"
    tools:context="com.MyDialog">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialog"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

When SeekBarChange, the `onProgressChanged()` of `OnSeekBarChangeListener` will be called, and the background of the screen(`LinearLayout`) will be updated according to the value (`SeekBar.getProgress()`).

You can do like the following:

```
package com.exercise.seekcolor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class SeekColorActivity extends Activity {

private int seekR, seekG, seekB;
SeekBar redSeekBar, greenSeekBar, blueSeekBar;
LinearLayout mScreen;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mScreen = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myScreen);
    redSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_R);
    greenSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_G);
    blueSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.mySeekingBar_B);
    updateBackground();

    redSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
    greenSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
    blueSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);

}

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener
= new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
  boolean fromUser) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
 updateBackground();
}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
};

private void updateBackground()
{
 seekR = redSeekBar.getProgress();
 seekG = greenSeekBar.getProgress();
 seekB = blueSeekBar.getProgress();
 mScreen.setBackgroundColor(
  0xff000000
  + seekR * 0x10000
  + seekG * 0x100
  + seekB
  );
}
}
```

Reference: [change-background-color-by-seekbar](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/08/change-background-color-by-seekbar.html).